Compare Resources variable with parameter in AzureDevOps pipeline template
I have a AzureDevOps YAML release pipeline which can be triggered by a pipeline it is dependent on:
release-pipeline.yaml
trigger: none

variables:
- group: DockerRegistries
- group: HelmTestEnv
- name: DBAAS_PIPELINE
  value: DBAAS

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Templates
    type: git
    name: Templates
    ref: main
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: DBAAS
    source: DBAAS
    trigger: true

stages:
- template: release.yaml@Templates
  parameters:
    PipelineDBAAS: DBAAS

This can be triggered manually or via the pipeline DBAAS and execute the release.yaml from the repository Templates.
release.yaml
parameters:
- name: PipelineDBAAS
  type: string

stages:
- stage: DefaultStage
  jobs:
  - job: DoesThisFixThings
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo '$(Resources.TriggeringAlias)'
        echo '${{ parameters.PipelineDBAAS }}'
        echo '$(Build.Reason)'
    - ${{ if eq(variables['Resources.TriggeringAlias'], parameters['PipelineDBAAS']) }}:
      - bash: |
          echo 'TriggeringAlias == [PipelineDBAAS]'
    - ${{ if eq(variables['Resources.TriggeringAlias'], parameters.PipelineDBAAS) }}:
      - bash: |
          echo 'TriggeringAlias == PipelineDBAAS'
    - ${{ if eq($(Resources.TriggeringAlias), 'DBAAS') }}:
      - bash: |
          echo 'TriggeringAlias == DBAAS'
    - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual') }}:
      - bash: |
          echo 'Build.Reason == Manual'
- ${{ if or(eq(variables['Resources.TriggeringAlias'], parameters.PipelineDBAAS), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual')) }}:
  - template: dbaas.yaml
    parameters:
      Pipeline: ${{ parameters.PipelineDBAAS }}

When running the DBAAS pipeline, the release-pipeline is triggered and starts ONLY the DoesThisFixThings stage. Not the stage defined in the dbaas.yaml.
Result in the DoesThisFixThings is 1 bash job:
Starting: Bash
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.236.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/ee24a525-d1f6-42dd-9c10-4afdf4da9b99.sh
DBAAS
DBAAS
ResourceTrigger

The first DBAAS is echo '$(Resources.TriggeringAlias)', the second is echo '${{ parameters.PipelineDBAAS }}'. But the comparison:
- ${{ if eq(variables['Resources.TriggeringAlias'], parameters.PipelineDBAAS) }}:
  - bash: |
    echo 'TriggeringAlias == PipelineDBAAS'

is not echoed correctly.
Is there a solution to this eq() to evaluate to true?

In Azure Pipelines, not all the variables are available in the template expression ${{ variables.var }}.
The variable Resources.TriggeringAlias seems is not available in template expression. So, the expression ${{ variables['Resources.TriggeringAlias'] }} is not valid/recognized in pipeline.
To conditionally run the stage defined in the dbaas.yaml, you can use the condition key apply the conditions on the stage level. For example.
# dbaas.yaml

stages:
- stage: DBAAS
  condition: or(eq(variables['Resources.TriggeringAlias'], '${{ parameters.PipelineDBAAS }}'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'))

